# como conectar o javascript ao webservice?

Tags: javascript

Após dias e dias de pesquisas, venho clamar a todos vocês que salvem o meu semestre.

O que eu quero é bem simples: conectar meu front-end javascript com o meu web service REST em java.

Apenas como teste, criei um método GET que retorna todos os elementos do meu banco (em xml, pois o JSON não está funcionando) :

```
@GET
@Override
@Path("teste")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Aluno> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

pois bem. O problema é que eu não faço ideia do que fazer no meu javascript para:
1. se comunicar com esse webservice e 
2: capturar os valores retornado desse xml

meu javascript (que nao está funncionando, esse codigo peguei aqui no forum):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.1.100:8080/SemanaEngenharia/webresources/service.aluno/teste",
    sucess: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        document.getElementByClassName(tituloFormulario).value = data;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: A princípio tem dois erros: o correto é `getElementsByClassName` ("Elements" no plural) e é preciso um índice, porque o `getElementsByClassName` retorna um _nodelist_, logo seria `document.getElementByClassName(tituloFormulario)[0].value = data;` para alterar o `value` do primeiro elemento da classe. O índice `[0]` é o primeiro elemento.

Comment: E a variável `tituloFormulario` deve ser um nome de classe.

Comment: sam, obrigado pela resposta, fiz as alterações que sugeriu (document.getElementsByClassName(tituloFormulario)[0].value = data;) e sim, tituloFormulario é o nome de uma classe de um campo aleatorio que usei so pra ver o retorno do web service. Porém ao atualizar a pagina, nao tem efeito algum, nao faço a minima ideia do que pode estar errado :/

Comment: Faltou um "c" no "success".

Comment: tambem ja corrigi haha. O engraçado é que esse codigo impede que meu javascript funcione, quando removo, volta a funcionar normalmente

Comment: Vc carregou a biblioteca do jQuery?

Comment: sim sim, está tudo funcionando normalmente. O meu real problema é que eu nao sei comunicar o javascript com o webservice, por isso nao consigo distinguir o que está errado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85856/discussion-between-sam-and-weslley-fillipe).

Answer (score -1):

Sugiro você estudar como retornar um JSON usando o JAava e depois tentar conectar, tira o data do alert e coloca um console.log()

```
console.log(data)
```

Outra sugestão é você olhar se tá ocorrendo algum erro no chrome devtools. Possivelmente pode ser problema de CORS, você tem que dizer para o seu servidor, que esse endereço pode acessar os recursos necessários. Informe pra gente ou coloque seu projeto no github para a gente entender o contexto.

Comment: ola Iago! Obrigado pela ajuda, realmente era o CORS que estava atrapalhando. Agora estou tentando salvar um formulário no banco de dados atraves do ajax, mas nao entendo como funciona, voce sabe?

Comment: atualmente o meu codigo é esse: (hospedei em formato de imagem para nao ficar confuso) 

https://ibb.co/hKUhkL

onde url carrega o caminho para o metodo salvar no meu web service, esse metódo é assim:

https://ibb.co/dEjF5L

Agora eu nao sei enviar o formulário pelo ajax como JSON, afim de que o webservice receba e salve no banco.